# PHP google drive files list doesn't work

Tags: php, google-drive-api

```
<?php

require_once './src/Google_Client.php';
require_once './src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("test");
$client->setClientId('test.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('test');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://test.com/');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly'));

if(empty($_GET['code']))
{
    $client->authenticate();
}


$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);


    $response = http_get("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=mimeType+%3D+'audio%2Fmpeg'&fields=items(title%2CwebContentLink)&key=".$accessToken);
    print_r($response);


?>
```

this GET files list doesn't work.

how can i get files list like that? mimetype : audio/mpeg and fields get title and webcontentlink.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you building a GET request?  You should be [using the API to list files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#examples)

I'm not 100% sure how to go about incorporating the information from the "[Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters)" doc, but rather than building that query directly like you are, you should be attempting to leverage the library.